# Resetting progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So i have a questionnaire which has some animation that is a progress bar that increases once a user has selected a radio button. I can get the reset button to reset the answers and take the bar down to nothing however if the user then goes to select a radio button they have not selected before, the bar automatically jumps back to the previous state + 1.

I'm trying to reset the question object back to 0, whilst it comes up in the developer tools the "q1" etc are at 0 again, the value still jumps up to +1

This is the html code to call the reset button

```
   <!-- First Container -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
  <h3 class="margin">Questionnaires</h3>

    <div class="container-main bg-5">
<button style="float:left" onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

  <h1>What IT sector could suit you</h1>
  <p>Take the questionnaire below!</p>

  <form id="quiz">
    <!-- Question 1 -->
    <h2>Do you enjoy fixing things</h2>
    <!-- Here are the choices for the first question. Each input tag must have the same name. For this question, the name is q1. -->
    <!-- The value is which answer the choice corresponds to. -->

      <div class="questions">
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c1">
      Yes
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c2">
      No
    </label><br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="c3">
      Maybe
    </label><br />
      </div>


    <div class="questions">
      <!--Question 5 -->
      <h2>Hardware or Software?</h2>
      <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c1">
          Hardware</label><br />
       <label><input type="radio" name="q5" value="c2">
         Software</label><br />
      </div>

    <button type='button' id="submit" onclick="tabulate()">Submit Your Answers</button>
  <button type="reset" id="reset" onclick="resetAnswer()">Reset</button>
  </form>

  <div id ="progressbar-1"></div>


</div>
```

This is the code to reset the bar

```
           <script>

// program the reset button
  function resetAnswer() {

       var progress = document.getElementById('progress');
             var total_questions = 5;
    //need this to check if the question has not been answered before


    // progress bar Calculation
    var result =  progress / total_questions;
    result = result * 100;

       $("input:radio").removeAttr("checked");

    $("#progressbar-1").css({'width':result-result,'background-color':'white'});


         var questions = {
        "q1": 0,
        "q2":0,
        "q3":0,
        "q4":0,
        "q5":0
    }
      console.log(questions);
        console.log("q1");



    }


    </script>
```

Below is the code i've used with major help to increase the bar

```
 <script>
 var progress = 0;
 var total_questions = 5;
    //need this to check if the question has not been answered before
    var questions = {
        "q1": 0,
        "q2":0,
        "q3":0,
        "q4":0,
        "q5":0
    }
    $( function() {
        $("#progressbar-1").text(progress)
        $("input, select").change( function() {
            el_name = $(this).attr("name");


            switch (this.nodeName.toLowerCase()) {
                case "select":
                    field =$("[name='"+el_name+"']");
                    val = (field.val() === ""  || !field.val()) ? null: field.val();
                    break;
                case "input":
                    field =$("[name='"+el_name+"']:checked");
                    val = field.length;
                    break;
            }

            if (val) {

                if (!questions[el_name]) {
                    progress = progress +1;
                    questions[el_name]=1
                }

            } else {


                questions[el_name]=0
                progress = (progress > 0)?progress-1:0;


            }
                        var result =  progress / total_questions;
            result = result * 100;

            $("#progressbar-1").css({'width':result+'%','background-color':'red'});
            $("#progressbar-1").text(progress);
        })
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: your `reset` button is supposed to reset the progress right? regardless of progress, it should just reset everything to 0? is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you over-complicate your `reset` method. 
If you just want to reset the `questions` object, you should not re-declare it in `reset` method. Removing `var` will solve your issue.

```
var questions = {
    "q1": 0,
    "q2":0,
    "q3":0,
    "q4":0,
    "q5":0
}
```

`Reset answer` method

```
function resetAnswer() {

  $("input:radio").prop("checked", false);

  $("#progressbar-1").css({
    'width': 0,
    'background-color': 'white'
  })
  .text("0");


  progress = 0;
  questions = {
    "q1": 0,
    "q2": 0,
    "q3": 0,
    "q4": 0,
    "q5": 0
  };

  console.log(questions);
}
```

Complete jsfiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/t4e5vuxe/